# Java call in XSL, wrong parameter type

Tags: java, xml, string, xslt

So I have a XLST to fill many fields in the SOAP Header. One of these fields needs call a java function in order to fill the value. The parameters of java function are String parameters, but I don't know how to create the parameters as string. I can't use XSLT 2.0, so I can't declare a parameter as string.

**Any idea how To convert the parameters `strBS` and `strCC` to string?**

When I execute the xsl then returns me a error:

> Incompatible types

Below is my stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"     
                xmlns:n0="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/serviceReenvioVale" 
                xmlns:ser="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/serviceReenvioVale" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns:javamap="java:dafiti.getloginhandler"  
                xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="n0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:param name="strBS">"BS_DFD_300"</xsl:param>

<xsl:param name="strCC">"CC_RFC_RCV"</xsl:param>

<xsl:param name="container" />

<xsl:template match="/">     
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header>
            <SessionHeader>
                <sessionId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="javamap:GetHandler($strBS,$strCC, $container)"/>
                </sessionId>   
            </SessionHeader>        
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ser:ReenviarVale>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="n0:ReenviarVale/*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </ser:ReenviarVale>             
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">                                                                                                                                                                    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    </xsl:element>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="@*">                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>                                                                                                                                                               
</xsl:template>                                                                                                                                                                                          

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The exact details of calling "extension functions" vary from processor to processor. You haven't told us which XSLT processor you're using, and it's hard to answer this question without that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using the [string()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string) function:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="javamap:GetHandler(string($strBS), 
                                         string($strCC), 
                                         string($container))"/>
```

Also, your `strBS` and `strCC` param values contain quotes as part of their value. Is that what you want? Are you sure you don't mean to define them like this:

```
<xsl:param name="strBS">BS_DFD_300</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="strCC">CC_RFC_RCV</xsl:param>
```

You would only need to wrap the values in quotes if you were specifying literal string values in the select attribute, like this:

```
<xsl:param name="strBS" select="'BS_DFD_300'"/>
<xsl:param name="strCC" select="'CC_RFC_RCV'"/>
```

Comment: tks a lot by your promptly the response